# Abstract interface cannot be used as type in array - missing property

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript2.0, tsc

I have this interface:

```
export interface SceEvent {
  // ...
}

export interface SceMain {

  onComplete: () => void;

  onNextEvent: (ev: SceEvent) => void;

  getRawGeneratedCode: () => string;

  getStyledGeneratedCode: () => string;

}
```

I implement this interface in several files that look like this:

```
import {SceEvent, SceMain} from "../../interfaces";

export class CodeGenerator implements SceMain {

  private rawCode = '';
  private styledCode = '';
  public static pluginName = 'java-junit';

  constructor(){

  }

  getRawGeneratedCode() {
    return this.rawCode;
  }


  getStyledGeneratedCode() {
    return this.styledCode;
  }

  onComplete(){

  }


  onNextEvent(ev: SceEvent) {

  }

}
```

then in another file, I export all of these implementations:

```
import {SceMain} from "./interfaces";

// generators
import * as javajunit from './values/java-junit';
import * as javatestng from './values/java-test-ng';
import * as nodejsmocha from './values/nodejs-mocha';
import * as nodejssuman from './values/nodejs-suman';


export const plugins : Array<SceMain>= [

  javajunit.CodeGenerator,
  javatestng.CodeGenerator,
  nodejsmocha.CodeGenerator,
  nodejssuman.CodeGenerator

];
```

but I am getting this error:

> Property "onComplete" is missing in typeof CodeGenerator

I don't get it, because all of my CodeGenerator classes implement this method.

Here is the error at an image...

[image]

Does anyone know what might be going on here?

Comment: For `plugins` you have made an array of `SceMain` *constructors*, not an array of `SceMain` *instances*.  The constructors don't have, for example,  `onComplete()` methods (the methods are not `static`).  Perhaps you should have passed instances, e.g., `plugins: Array<SceMain>= [ new javajunit.CodeGenerator(), ...  ]`?

Comment: yeah I need to pass the constructors in the array, not instances, so what do I do yo

Comment: Then `plugins` is typed wrong.  It should be something like `plugins: Array<new() => SceMain>`, assuming all the constructors are no-arg.

Comment: ok that sounds about right...want to add an answer and collect some points?

Comment: seems weird to me though, instances of `CodeGenerator` are gonna have the methods defined in `SceMain`..so...in Java my original pattern would work tmk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `plugins` constant is an array of `SceMain` *constructors*, not an array of `SceMain` *instances*.  An instance of `SceMain` has methods like `onComplete()`, but a constructor does not (unless it happens to have static methods with the right signatures). The compiler is warning you that the elements of the array are not instances of `SceMain`.

Assuming you actually intend to create an array of constructors (as you mentioned in your comment), you should type `plugins` like:

```
export const plugins : Array<new() => SceMain>= [    
  javajunit.CodeGenerator,
  javatestng.CodeGenerator,
  nodejsmocha.CodeGenerator,
  nodejssuman.CodeGenerator    
];
```

The type `new() => SceMain` is the type of a no-argument constructor which produces an `SceMain` instance.  (If your constructors take arguments then the type should be modified.)

---

Your confusion quite possibly stems from the fact that in TypeScript, when you declare a named `class` like `class Foo {}`, it creates a *type* named `Foo`, corresponding to *instances* of the class, and a *value* named `Foo`, which is the constructor of the class.  The value `Foo` is not of type `Foo`.  It is, however, of type `new ()=>Foo`.  You can get a more specific type of a class constructor (including static methods) by using the `typeof` type operator: `typeof Foo` is the type of the `Foo` constructor.  You can read about this more in the [TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#advanced-techniques).

The distinction between type expressions and value expressions is tricky to explain, especially since TypeScript tends to use the same keywords in both kinds of expression to mean different (and possibly only marginally related) things:

```
class Foo {}

const foo: Foo = new Foo();  
// the first Foo is the instance type, 
// the second Foo is the constructor value

const fooConstructor: typeof Foo = Foo; 
// the first Foo is the constructor value
// typeof is a type query acting on it at design time
// the second Foo is the constructor value

const theWordFunction: string = typeof Foo;
// Foo is the constructor value
// typeof is the JavaScript typeof operator acting on it at runtime
// It will just be "function"
```

I don't know if that cleared things up or made it worse.  Anyway, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Because plugins is an array of constructors, not an array of instances, then the type needs to change:

// original

```
plugins: Array<SceMain>
```

// improved

```
plugins: Array<new() => SceMain>
```

thanks to @jcalz for the answer